# How to acces useRef value Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a react native image crop view and I am using :
https://github.com/hhunaid/react-native-image-crop-tools#readme

After a bit of fixing it works and apparenty there is automatically an output generated:

https://ibb.co/SBLvFGY

My question is, how can I get the value of the useRef Hook, since I want to store it in redux, it all is immensly confusing to me, the code :

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { CropView } from 'react-native-image-crop-tools';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changeNewIdeaImage } from '../../redux/actions/';

const TestImageCropper = () => {
    const [uri, setUri] = useState();
    const cropViewRef = useRef();
    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button
                    title={'Pick Image'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
                            { noData: true },
                            (response) => {
                                setUri(response.uri);
                            }
                        );
                    }}
                />
                {uri !== undefined && (
                    <CropView
                        sourceUrl={uri}
                        style={styles.cropView}
                        ref={cropViewRef}
                        onImageCrop={(res) => console.warn(res)}
                        keepAspectRatio
                        aspectRatio={{ width: 4, height: 4 }}
                    />
                )}
                <Button
                    title={'Get Cropped View'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        cropViewRef.current.saveImage(true, 90);

                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    cropView: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
});

const mapStatetoProps = (state: any) => {};

export default TestImageCropper;
```

Now this is the most confusing part to me.Where does the saveImage view function even come from and how can I hook it up, so that I can save the Image uri in Redux, to display it?

```
 <Button
    title={'Get Cropped View'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        cropViewRef.current.saveImage(true, 90);

                    }}
                />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `saveImage()` seems like a method coming from `CropView`. Ref is simply storing - in your case - the rendered `CropView` element, so `cropViewRef.current` is basically the `CropView` in your `TestImageCropper` component, and you call it's built-in method with `cropViewRef.current.saveImage(true, 90);`

What not clear to me, is what is it that you want to store in redux? The value of the ref is the element itself.

Comment: Thanks maten, do you know how I could access the saved uri?

Comment: @Fredyonge I'm not familiar with the package itself, but is saveImage() returning anything at all?

Comment: I tried const test = cropViewRef.current.saveImage(true, 90); , but its not returning anything

Comment: @Fredyonge it's a wild guess, but I think it's either gets updated in the state, or the image gets saved to the device